# Problem with \printindex. No index created

Tags: indexing, logging

I tried to create an index to a document I write, but when viewing the `.pdf` output there was no index. Also no error messages were displayed. I managed to find this in the LOG FILE:
`No file "Actual Document".ind.
("Actual Document.aux") )`
Indeed, when I check the folder supposed to have these files, I found only a file `Actual Document.idx` with all my indices, but no `.ind` file. Changing the extension `.idx` to `.ind` produced an error.
Here is what I have written:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
continuous \index{continuous}
\clearpage
\printindex
\end{document}
```

What have I done wrong and what is going on with these files?

Comment: you need to run `makeindex` to generate the index

Comment: Hello! `:)` You need to run `makeindex "Actual Document.idx"`, which will give you a `"Actual Document.ilg"` file, containing your index. Then rerun `pdflatex "Actual Document.tex"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `makeidx` package doesn't produce the index on its own; it just writes the entries, unsorted, to a separate file.  You need to use an external processor, such as `makeindex` or `xindy`, to sort the index and format it in a way appropriate for inclusion in your document.

So your compilation process might look like this:

```
pdflatex jobname.tex
```

This produces a `jobname.pdf` file and writes the index entries to `jobname.idx`.

```
makeindex jobname.idx
```

This sorts and formats the index entries and outputs `jobname.ind`.

```
pdflatex jobname.tex
```

This produces a `pdf` file and includes `jobname.ind` at whatever point in the document you issued `\printindex`.

Oftentimes, it's good to put these commands into a script so you don't forget to run them.

Remember that every time you compile your document, it is *both* including the contents of `jobname.ind` at whatever point you issued `\printindex` *and* writing all your index entires to `jobname.idx`.  Once you have your `ind` file, you don't need to rerun `makeindex` unless your page numbers have changed or you've changed entries in the index.

Comment: The problem is that `\makeindex` doesn't produce the `jobname.idn` file. I do have the `.idx` file, though.

Comment: Right; `makeindex` does that.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I do have `\makeindex`. I don't have the `.idn` file. @dgoodmaniii

Comment: Not `\makeindex`; `makeindex`.  It's not a command you issue in your document; it's a command you run outside your document, on the `idx` file that LaTeX created. As the answer explains, compiling your document produces the `idx` file.  You need to process the `idx` file now with `makeindex`.  So don't run LaTeX again; run `makeindex jobname.idx`, from the command line or your IDE.  That will produce the `ind` file.  Run LaTeX on your document again now, and you'll get your index wherever you have `\printindex`.

Comment: OK, I think I got now how it is working, but I'm not sure how to run an external program. I tried through `run` of Windows where I typed `makeindex Actual Document.idx` and some other variations. No `.idn` prodused. What am I missing again?

Comment: I'm a Unix and derivatives guy, not a Windows guy; sorry.  If you're using TeXStudio or something, there's probably a "Build" button or something that will take care of it for you.  Otherwise, you'll need to navigate to your working directory to run it manually there.

Comment: @Jim Spaces in filenames are evil.

Answer (score 3):

Although the question has been answered, there still some clarifications that need to be made regarding Windows users.

To run `makeindex` in Windows you have to go to the terminal which is what Windows call `Command Prompt` or `cmd`. You can search for these manually or type them into the `run` program that appears in `Start`. Once you have opened the terminal, you can use **Unix** commands to do whatever. `makeindex` is a **Unix** command, too, and only works into this terminal.

Comment: I think every decent LaTeX editor has a button to run `makeindex`. No need to get into a terminal.

Comment: @Johannes_B: That's true but it does not prevent to use a terminal. I prefer terminal commands even on Windows (although I use that 'system' very rarely)

Comment: @Johannes_B I'm using `TexMaker` version 4.5. I cannot find a built-in button anywhere.

Comment: In my version of texmaker, it is called by pressing F12. Or clicking on `makeindex` in the `tools` menu.

Comment: F12 works perfectly. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem of running

```
makeindex "filename with spaces.idx"
```

I wrote a batch file **index.bat** in order to avoid these white spaces either in the file name or in the path name:

```
e:
cd "my path to my document"
makeindex main.idx
set /p DUMMY=Hit ENTER to continue...
```

The batch file waits for a keyboard hit after having run. Do not call the batch file **makeindex.bat** because then it can occur that it calls itself in an infinite loop!

Answer (score -1):

On Windows assuming you have `makeindex` installed and on your PATH the procedure that should be followed is:

Compile your `.tex` document as usual.

Open the Windows command prompt, this can be done by searching for `cmd`.
In the command prompt execute (type in and hit enter)

```
cd C:\Users\<username>\<path to file>
```

where you replace `<username>` and `<path to file>` with the user name and full path to the folder containing your `.tex` file.
If this contains spaces include the whole path in quotation marks, as in

```
cd "C:\Users\<username>\<path to file with spaces>"
```

Then, assuming that your `.tex` is called `main.tex`, execute

```
makeindex main
```

Compile your `.tex` again and the index should now be complete.

Many (La)TeX editors also allow you to specify commands, like `makeindex` to run at compile time which will do all of this automatically.